# Laravel 10 | Optimization of a section of code that creates a new order

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I've written a function that creates a new order of scripts, but on my mind, this code is very unoptimized, unreadable and time-consuming.

Mostly I don't like a section which filters scripts. I think, it's not right to make many requests to database in map.

What can I do to make it better?

The function is below.

```
/**
     * @param array $request_data
     * @return Order
     * @throws AuthException
     * @throws OrderException
     * @throws AuthException|PromocodeException
     */
    public function create(array $request_data): Order
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) throw AuthException::unauthenticated();

        /**
         * @var User $user
         */
        $user = auth()->user();

        $promocode_service = new PromocodeService();
        $user_service = new UserService();

        $order_data = [
            "user_id" => $user->id,
            "scripts" => [],
            "cost" => 0,
            "promocode_id" => null
        ];

        //Filtering scripts, checking if the user already has any selected scripts, counting the total cost
        collect($request_data["scripts"])->map(function (int $id) {
            return Script::find($id);
        })->reject(function ($id){
            return empty($id);
        })->map(function (Script $script) use (&$order_data, $user_service, $user) {

            if ($user_service->hasScript($user, $script))
            {
                throw OrderException::alreadyHasScript($script->name);
            }

            $order_data["scripts"][] = $script->id;
            $order_data["cost"] += $script->cost;
            return $script;
        });

        if (!count($order_data["scripts"])) throw OrderException::noScriptIsSelected();

        //Using promo code
        if (isset($request_data["promocode"]))
        {
            $use_promocode = $promocode_service->useByName($request_data["promocode"], $data["cost"]);
            $order_data["cost"] = $use_promocode["new_cost"];
            $order_data["promocode_id"] = $use_promocode["promocode_id"];
        }

        if ($order_data["cost"] > $user->balance) throw OrderException::notEnoughMoney();

        /**
         * @var Order $order
         */
        $order = $user->orders()->create($order_data);
        $order->scripts()->sync($order_data["scripts"]);
        $user->update(["balance" => $user->balance - $order_data["cost"]]);
        $user->scripts()->attach($order_data["scripts"]);


        return $order;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the query in the loop and fetch all the necessary data in one query.
Also use dependency injection to make the code more flexible and testable.

```
/**
 * @param array $request_data
 * @param PromocodeService $promocodeService
 * @param UserService $userService
 * @return Order
 */
public function create(array $request_data, PromocodeService $promocodeService, UserService $userService): Order
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    if (!$user) {
        throw AuthException::unauthenticated();
    }

    $order_data = [
        "user_id" => auth()->id(),
        "scripts" => [],
        "cost" => 0,
        "promocode_id" => null
    ];

    $scriptIds = collect($request_data["scripts"])->filter(fn($id) => !empty($id));

    $scripts = Script::whereIn('id', $scriptIds)->get();

    $existingScripts = $userService->getExistingScripts($user, $scripts);

    foreach ($scripts as $script) {
        if ($existingScripts->contains($script->id)) {
            throw OrderException::alreadyHasScript($script->name);
        }

        $order_data["scripts"][] = $script->id;
        $order_data["cost"] += $script->cost;
    }

    if (empty($order_data["scripts"])) {
        throw OrderException::noScriptIsSelected();
    }

    // Use promo code
    if (isset($request_data["promocode"])) {
        $use_promocode = $promocodeService->useByName($request_data["promocode"], $order_data["cost"]);
        $order_data["cost"] = $use_promocode["new_cost"];
        $order_data["promocode_id"] = $use_promocode["promocode_id"];
    }

    if ($order_data["cost"] > $user->balance) {
        throw OrderException::notEnoughMoney();
    }

    $order = $user->orders()->create($order_data);
    $user->scripts()->sync($order_data["scripts"]);
    $user->update(["balance" => $user->balance - $order_data["cost"]]);
    $user->scripts()->attach($order_data["scripts"]);

    return $order;
}
```